# json_decode produces error "Single unpaired UTF-16 surrogate in unicode escape" and returns null

Tags: php, json

json_decode produces null results from valid json string , with the error "Single unpaired UTF-16 surrogate in unicode escape"

Comment: Wow, we are going to need a LOT more information that THAT. Got anything you can add?

Comment: I just want to remove this "Single unpaired UTF-16 surrogate" from string

Answer (score -6, accepted):

I solved with custom json_decode function as below:

```
function custom_json_decode($json)
{
    $comment = false;
    $out = '$x=';
    for ($i=0; $i<strlen($json); $i++) {
         if (!$comment) {
             if (($json[$i] == '{') || ($json[$i] == '[')) $out .= ' array('; else if (($json[$i] == '}') || ($json[$i] == ']')) $out .= ')'; else if ($json[$i] == ':') $out .= '=>';
    else
    $out .= $json[$i];
    }
    else
    $out .= $json[$i];
    if ($json[$i] == '"' && $json[($i-1)]!="\\")
    $comment = !$comment;
    }
    eval($out . ';');
    return $x;
}

custom_json_decode($data);
```

Comment: Good grief, do not use this function. I hate that this is the first Google result for this problem. Care to guess what is going to happen when I pass `'print_r($_SERVER)'` as an input to a function that uses `eval`?