# PHP json_decode not working well on local server, but fine on web server

Tags: php, json

I've a JSON file that I'm trying to decode in PHP. This seems to work just fine when I do it on my web-server, but when trying on my local server, using the same exact file, I get NULL back.
Other files are decoded just fine across both servers, so I'm really clueless why this specific file is not.

The JSON file could be found here:
http://boghdady.com/samsung_Page_1_Results.json

My webserver is on PHP v5.6 while the local one is on 7.2. I've verified that the file syntax is fine, using https://www.freeformatter.com/json-validator.html

Echoing json_last_error on my local server outputs 10. I've tried all sorts of functions to convert the string to UTF-8 ahead of doing the json_decode, but results remain NULL. This is even though the file is originally in UTF-8 anyways.

Could anybody please help with this? As it is really driving me nuts.

Update 1, regarding the proposed solution from the other similar question:
I've tried applying the fix indicated in [json_decode produces error "Single unpaired UTF-16 surrogate in unicode escape" and returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47856350/json-decode-produces-error-single-unpaired-utf-16-surrogate-in-unicode-escape)
However, the eval() there lead to even more problems. Some of the text within the JSON string was considered as a variable by PHP, and thus it failed. Some examples of the errors received:

```
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: GSI_TCPIP_IP_ADDR in <b>C:\Users\boghdady\Desktop\Server\Shodan\include\functions.php(73) : eval()'d code</b> on line <b>1</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: O in <b>C:\Users\boghdady\Desktop\Server\Shodan\include\functions.php(73) : eval()'d code</b> on line <b>1</b><br />
<br />
```

Is it possible to explain to me the issue within the JSON file in more details? I could write a function to fix it if I understand what it is.

Comment: try to use `json_last_error_msg()` ([doc here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php)) to have the error message.

Comment: Error `Single unpaired UTF-16 surrogate in unicode escape`

Comment: ...and that error was introduced in PHP 7.0, which is why you didn't get it in previous versions.

Comment: Thank you for that, I wasn't aware of this function. Gives me exactly what RiggsFolly just posted, Single unpaired UTF-16 surrogate in unicode escape

Comment: Have you tried using `utf8_encode`? You could do something like this `json_decode(utf8_encode($data))`

Comment: @Efekan No that does not solve it, I tried :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [json\_decode produces error "Single unpaired UTF-16 surrogate in unicode escape" and returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47856350/json-decode-produces-error-single-unpaired-utf-16-surrogate-in-unicode-escape)

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton yes sorry but i've seen your post so i've removed mine. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: @AlexandrePainchaud Of course :)

Comment: Odd that jsonlint.com validates it fine

Comment: I've tried the proposed solution from the other similar question, but it lead to more errors. I've edited my post to indicate the issues I had faced

Comment: An acutal sample + hexdump of the JSON data would have been more useful. Unlikely that those notices are relevant.